# dhungar method: How can I make smoky dal tadka without charcoal?

Tags: indian-cuisine

Normally one is to get a piece of charcoal red-hot, put it in a small metal cup, put some ghee on it to burn/smoke, and put it in the pot with the finished dal tadka curry.

I don't have charcoal.  And even if I bought charcoal I don't have a gas burner to heat it.  I have IH burners (electric induction heating, which can't heat charcoal).

Comment: Have you thought about using liquid smoke?

Comment: Yes I've thought of it but here in Japan it's not available that I can see.  Buying on Amazon is like $5 for the liquid smoke plus $25 for shipping for US or Australia!

Comment: that would be a great reason not to use it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a bowl that your curry fits into, and that in turn fits in a tall pot.

Put the ghee in the bottom of the tall pot, and the bowl into the pot.  Put a tight lid and set to highest temperature for 5-15 minutes.  Observe the smoke if you have a glass lid and experiment to find the best results for you.

This also warms up the curry if it is leftovers.

I was worried about the unequal heat shattering my ceramic bowl, so I rested it on a small silicone trivet meant to be good for any temperature that the pot could reach.

Comment: You could also use a steaming rack [like this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/41Bb%2BT4oUWL._AC_.jpg), which are usually metal.

Answer (score 2):

Smoked salt for general use in kitchen to get "smoked/grilled" taste or for dal tadka smoked chilli pepper. Latter is no so strong as normal chilli (so you use more) but give nice aftertaste to spiceness.

Comment: We cook a lot with Hungarian smoked paprika (Chicken Paprikash, etc.)  so I used a bit of that instead of the recommended Kashmiri chili powder.  However I wasn't able to use enough of it to really make a difference.  Further, I'm worried that if I used enough to make it smoky, I'll have also made my dal curry taste like Hungarian food :-D

Comment: @SwissFrank smoked salt have this ability that is don't make food salty. So you can make it taste smoked without any fear of changing the taste.

Answer (score 2):

**Ghee candle.**

**[image: Ghee candle.]**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge1O9rH__5Y

Depicted: butter candle from the King of Random.  It is basically a half stick of butter with a toilet paper wick. You can see it gives off a little smoke as it burns.  That smoke is the flavor you want - burned butter flavor.

Make a ghee candle.  Put it in a pot with your curry.  The pot will become a smoke chamber.  You will need to work with the lid to figure out how much of an opening you need - you want the smoke to stay in there and flavor your curry but you need some air to feed the candle.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up burning my last dal tadka a little bit, so the result tasted smokey anyway!

I don't suggest this as a *good* answer.  I only record it as *an* answer...